Spark Shell with S3, Hudi and EMR. org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
Following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hudi-work-with-dataset.html
spark-shell --jars /usr/lib/hudi/hudi-spark-bundle.jar \
--conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" \    
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog"  \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension"

scala> // Write the DataFrame as a Hudi dataset

scala> (inputDF.write
     |     .format("hudi")
     |     .options(hudiOptions)
     |     .option(DataSourceWriteOptions.OPERATION_OPT_KEY,"insert")
     |     .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
     |     .save("s3a://oh-project-sunnyvalelabs-observed/marketing/"))
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found

A similar error but if you save to a s3 instead of a s3a bucket.
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"


Need to rewrite the spark shell to include the hudi-aws-bundle jar which contains the S3 libraries.
spark-shell --jars /usr/lib/hudi/hudi-spark-bundle.jar,/usr/lib/hudi/hudi-aws-bundle.jar \
--conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" \    
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog"  \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension"

